# How to set up correctly the OSMbonuspack in my project?

Tags: android, android-studio, osmdroid, osmbonuspack

Hello guys I tried to install the osmbonuspack in an Android Studio project. I tried this with the osmbonuspack wiki, but when I try to sync my project I get an error in this dependency. I assume that this is a compatibility problem. Can you please suggest me a solution?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mytestapplication.hello.com.map"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.5.2'

}
```

-This dependency returns the error:implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Answer (score 2):

SDK 28 is not compatible with appcompat-v7.

You can now upgrade to osmbonuspack 6.5.3, which get rid from this dependency to appcompat-v7. 
(and also upgrade to osmdroid 6.0.3)